# .net Upload image to google storage

Tags: .net, google-cloud-storage

Greetings im trying to upload an image to Google Cloud storage in .net
it works it uploads but the problem is when i upload it it appears like the image below

[image]
on the other hand if i upload from angular it uploads fine but i can access the image and it appears like this

[image]
can anyone help me

i use this code

```
 Public Sub UploadFile(bucketName As String, local Path As String, storage As StorageClient, objectName As String)
    Using F = File.OpenRead(localPath)
        objectName = "z1.png"
        storage.UploadObject(bucketName, objectName, Nothing, F)
        Console.WriteLine(objectName)
    End Using
End Sub
```

what i have notices the one in angular has access token automatically but the one in the.net does not

Comment: It's a known issue that the Firebase console doesn't show previews for images that were not directly uploaded by a client app using the Firebase client library.  Feel free to file a feature request with Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: but can u get the download link  from it

Comment: Yeah, you have to do that from the mobile client with a download url.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url